# PHP Image converter system

Tags: php, image, converters

How to write an image converter system in PHP, which can converted an uploaded .jpeg, .png .bmp or .gif file into another type given by the uploader. The system automatically detects the type of the uploaded file and it can't be greater than 2 MB?

Comment: Did you ever spent more than 10 seconds for research before asking this question?

Comment: try this https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: You basically have to use the [GD library functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) for that. Your question is too general, you'll only get better answers if you post a more specific issue. Also, if your don't know how to handle uploads with PHP, read [the manual section about Handling Uploads](http://br2.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use [GD and Image functions in PHP](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)

an example to convert png to jpeg(ignoring transperancy) would be

```
// Quality is a number between 0 (best compression,low quality) and 100 (best quality)
function png2jpg($originalFile, $outputFile, $quality) {
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($originalFile);
    imagejpeg($image, $outputFile, $quality);
    imagedestroy($image);
}
```

This function uses the imagecreatefrompng() and the imagejpeg() functions from the [GD library.](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)